# How to disable date for Sat/ Sun and any holidays in adaptive card Input.Date

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am integrating adaptive cards in Microsoft teams bot framework. As per my requirement I need to disable some dates like sat,sun and holidays. Is this possible. Please help me if it's possible.

Input Design JSON:
{
"spacing": "Small",
"id": "date",
"type": "Input.Date",
"separator": true,
"value": ""
}

Comment: Hey, i'm afraid this is not possible as of today. You would have to validate the selected dates in your backend and return an error.